# Maven can't resolve depndency from GitLab private repo

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab

So like the title says I am using GitLab to host a number of spring boot projects. We also have a simple Maven package repository that hosts a common library used between various projects. I have followed the official documentation from GitLab. However Maven gives me an error when it tries to resolve dependencies.

I have tried deleting .m2 directory and cleared caches on intellij. Hoping to get some help in resolving this. Below you will find my pom.xml and the error message.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org   /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bidmii</groupId>
    <artifactId>bmf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bmf</name>
    <description>bidmii web application backend</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Bidmii internal dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bidmii</groupId>
            <artifactId>bidmii-core-data</artifactId>
            <version>1622132284.278f525b-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Third party dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.orbisgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2gis-functions</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- excludes JUnit 4.12 from spring-boot-starter-test -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.braintreepayments.gateway</groupId>
            <artifactId>braintree-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.87.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hyperwallet</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.1.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.113.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jhonnymertz</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>8.12.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-spatial -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectId>bidmii-beta-app</projectId>
                    <version>beta</version>
                    <appEngineDirectory>${basedir}</appEngineDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectid>/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Error message from maven.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bmf: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.bidmii:bmf:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.bidmii:bidmii-core-data:jar:1622132284.278f525b-SNAPSHOT in gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/26625326/packages/maven)
```

Comment: is https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/26625326/packages/maven available from the browser?

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov the link returns an error saying "invalid packag_id"

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem. It was an authentication problem related to the Deply-Token. The token the token that I was using was created under a co-worker's GitLab Account. Apparently when trying to pull a dependency from a GitLab package, you must use a Deply-Token created by your own account.